# altering a keyboard plugin core js

Tags: javascript, jquery

The demo is here, http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/docs/basic.html. The core js used is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mottie/Keyboard/master/js/jquery.keyboard.js.

How can I swap the `accept` and `cancel` button?

Comment: You should definitely post some sample code (not just links).

Comment: @grill the sample code is the core js.

Comment: Yes. Post the relevant portions inline to make life easy for people who might want to help.

Comment: try this . in JS find  `'{accept} {space} {cancel}'` and replace with `{cancel} {space} {accept}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You can achieve this without modifying the core JS file. Check**
>   **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/36/)  for custom layout**
>
> Check the block `$keyboard.layouts` in JS file for modifying the other
>   keyboard layouts

If you still want to modify the core file then just change this `{accept} {space} {cancel}` to `{cancel} {space} {accept}` in `keyboard.js`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orxnau02/)